# php/html display automatic week counter starting from a specific data

Tags: javascript, php, html, counter, week-number

Is there any coding (php / HTML or JS script) to display a week counter and start this counter from a specific date say i wanted to start this counter on Monday 25th March 2019 (and just display "Week 1"), then the number increases every week or 7 days (so on Monday 1st April 2019 it would change to "Week 2") until it gets to 52 weeks? Any help would be grateful!!!! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with plain JavaScript using the **Date** object.

First initialize a new Date from which you want to start counting

```
var startDate=new Date(2019,2,10); // will set the date to the 10th of March
```

Second get the actual time and date

```
var today=new Date();
```

Now simply get the difference between this two dates like this:

```
var difference=today-startDate;
```

This will return the difference in milliseconds.

To get the difference in days proceed like this

```
var days = difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Based on this you can get the number of weeks that passed by

```
var weeks = parseInt(days / 7);
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var startDate = new Date(2019, 2, 10);
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById("stDate").innerHTML = "target: <b>" + startDate.toDateString() + "</b>";
document.getElementById("cDate").innerHTML = "today: <b>" + today.toDateString() + "</b>";

var difference = today - startDate;
var days = difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
var weeks = parseInt(days / 7);
var messaged = "";
if (weeks < 1) {
  message = "no weeks have passed";
} else {
  message = "weeks passed: <b>" + weeks + "</b>";
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = message;
```

```html
<div id="stDate"></div><br>
<div id="cDate"></div><br>
<div id="result"></div><br>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your response could you explain how this code is laid out, sort new-ish js?

Comment: I'd love to help - unfortunately I didn't understand your question. What do you mean?

Comment: i guess i would like a automatic counter that starts at 1 however i don't no if this is possible to time it to start on a specific date (say 25th March 2019) then go up one number every 7 days - so the counter would change to 2 on the 1 st April 2019 (after 7 days) - does this make it any clearer?

Comment: In this case all you'd have to do is modify the startDate in my code above to reflect your target date e.g. `var startDate=new Date(2019,2,25);`
By the way the 2 means march because months start at 0. Well there's a problem now - `var weeks = parseInt(days / 7);` will return a negative number since the start
date is in the future - so you'd have to include some logic to compensate e.g. `if(weeks<1) { // don't do whatever } else { console.log(weeks + " have passed"); }`

Comment: sorry im a bit lost to what you have given me so is this correct:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var startDate=new Date(2019,2,25);
var weeks = parseInt(days / 7);
if(weeks<1) { // don't do whatever } else { console.log(weeks + " have passed"); }
</script>

</body>
</html> or could you show me the code in some preview mode?

Comment: I've included a working example in my answer above.

Comment: ok i see now I think this works - will the week number change once 7 days goes by automatically?

Comment: Whenever 7 days have passed from startDate (which is set to the 10th of march in the example), weeks will increment by one. So yes, it will. ;)